# Why is my toggle failing

Tags: jquery, css

I've done this countless times, and i swear it's just messing with me.

Using any jquery library.

All i'm trying to do is toggle a div via link.

```
<a href="" id="mGoldNav">Click Me</a>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
$('#mGoldNav').click(function(){
    $('#module-golden-nav').toggle("slow");
});
```

On my site, basically NOTHING happens. I placed an alert() and that fires off, so the click() works. But the toggle fails.

But on **http://jsfiddle.net/BaQd2/1/** you'll notice that it works once, but dissapears and if you RUN once more, it give me an odd error :  {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Any ideas why it's messing with me?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `e` as a param to your function in the click handler and `e.preventDefault();` within the function. On your site, make sure the code above is within a `$(function() {   ....   });` block.

Comment: it does happen, but it then gets overridden by the link action.

Answer (score 1):

Return `false` at the end of the click-callback to prevent the browsers default behavior of following a clicked anchor.

This should work:

```
$('#mGoldNav').click(function(){
    $('#module-golden-nav').toggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaQd2/4/)

Comment: either that or change markup  to be:`<a href="javascript: ;" id="mGoldNav">Click Me</a> ` or use a button instead of an anchor link...I like your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

As it is an anchor  tag, it will trigger its default postback action.. To use toggle you have to use

```
return false;
```

like this:

```
$('#mGoldNav').click(function(){
     $('#module-golden-nav').toggle("slow");
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just put something in your `href` attribute on your link, like a `#`. 
http://jsfiddle.net/BaQd2/2/

Comment: yea, i'm an idiot. I totally forgot to stop the link. I typically do href="javascript:void(0);". Thanks guys! Been a long week clearly LOL.

Answer (score 1):

`a` elements are actually bad idea to use them as buttons. But in your definition `href` attribute does the unwanted action, post back. if you change it like `#` (or `javascript:void(0)`) you will get what you want:

```
<a href="#" ..
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BaQd2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#mGoldNav').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#module-golden-nav').toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Well that works, but why the heck is the e.preventDefault needed all of a sudden?

Comment: preventdefault is functionally equivalent to the return false, which would also work

Comment: @E.J.Brennan Just FYI, returning false is similar to calling preventDefault on the event, but there is a difference. Returning false also stops the event from bubbling, which preventDefault does not. To stop bubbling in your case, you would have to call stopPropagation on the event as well.